# How to make button static and fixed at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, tailwind-css

I am working with **tailwind** CSS and making a page where it uses Next and Back buttons to navigate between pages. But the problem is when the content is less on the page the button sticks to the top You can see this image for more reference.

**Image link**:- https://ibb.co/pw5QN2N

**This is the code used for Buttons**

```
<div className="flex justify-between">
            <NavLink to={"/course/" + courseName + "/" + (+moduleID - 1)}>
              <button
                      className="my-8 float-right px-5 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm font-bold tracking-wide rounded-full focus:outline-none"
                    >
                      Back
                </button>
            </NavLink>
            {courseContent[courseName][+moduleID - 1].quiz === true ? (
              <NavLink to={"/course/" + courseName + "/" + +moduleID + "/quiz"}>
                <button
                      className="my-8 float-right px-5 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm font-bold tracking-wide rounded-full focus:outline-none"
                    >
                      Next (Quiz)
                </button>
              </NavLink>
            ) : (
              <NavLink to={"/course/" + courseName + "/" + (+moduleID + 1)}>
                <button
                      className="my-8 float-right px-5 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm font-bold tracking-wide rounded-full focus:outline-none"
                    >
                      Next
                </button>
              </NavLink>
            )}
            </div>
```

How can I fix this so that button becomes fixed to the bottom.

Comment: Hi, Can you create a codepen or fiddle for this?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap those buttons with `<div>` tag and add classes `fixed bottom-0 w-full` to that `<div>` tag.

Example:

```
<div class='fixed bottom-0 w-full'>
    <button class='my-8 float-right px-5 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm font-bold tracking-wide rounded-full focus:outline-none'>Back</button>
    <button class='my-8 ml-auto px-5 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm font-bold tracking-wide rounded-full focus:outline-none'>Next(Quiz)</button>
    <button class='bottom-0 my-8 float-right px-5 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm font-bold tracking-wide rounded-full focus:outline-none'>Next</button>
</div>
```

- `w-full` is for `width: 100%`
- `fixed` is for `position: fixed`
- `bottom-0` is for `bottom: 0`

Comment: This works but for other pages where there is enough content the buttons are getting sticky to the bottom https://ibb.co/3z6zMMM

Comment: Then you should use js for this. I think not able to do only with any css

Answer (score 1):

use this css on the main container div

```
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your buttons to be fixed to the bottom and not relative to the content above, then you might want to try this. It just sets the buttons to the bottom of the page and tells the code not to worry about the other content. You can then change the other CSS of the buttons (ie, how far left or right, or the color) individually.

```css
.b {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.next {
  right: 50px;
}

.back {
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<!--  you can still have your container -->
<div>content up here, buttons below</div>
<!-- you can still have your content -->
<button class="b next">next</button>
<!-- and your buttons will stick to the bottom -->
<button class="b back">back</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com//tailwindcss@2.1.1/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="flex flex-col justify-between min-h-screen p-5">
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">Cyber security</h1>
    <h1 class="mt-5 text-2xl font-medium text-blue-500">Basic Terms</h1>
    <p>Cybersecurity 101...</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <button class="px-5 py-2 text-sm font-bold tracking-wide text-white bg-red-500 rounded-full focus:outline-none">Back</button>
    <button class="px-5 py-2 text-sm font-bold tracking-wide text-white bg-red-500 rounded-full focus:outline-none">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/WY4qZvba15